# How to create a webform node while creating a page content type node?

Tags: drupal, content-type, cck

I have a situation where i have ti create a webform node when i will save my page type content
is this possible ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the webform as part of the same node as the page type.

Visit:

```
/admin/settings/weform
```

There you are able to set "WEBFORM-ENABLED CONTENT TYPES", eg. page, artical, blog etc.